# Xcode Codesign error: timestamps differ

Tags: xcode, timestamp, codesign

My attempts at signing my application within XCode are failing with an error "Code signing failed: check that the identity you selected is valid".
Since my certificates all check out as valid I tried using the codesign utility in Terminal.
When I run it with these parameters:
codesign --force --deep  -s  
I get this cryptic error:
timestamps differ by 230 seconds - check your system clock

I have research this error in the documentation and all over the web and found nothing.

Any ideas ?
Thank you.

Update - a few days later: I was able to dispense with this problem by getting fresh certificates and signing identity and doing a "Clean Build Folder" (hold the option key down when choosing Clean Build).

Comment: Maybe a time server problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the profiles may get messed up. In those cases I download them again. And (using the Finder) activate them by opening the profiles.

Nothing really spectacular happen, occasionally you may see the profiles flashing or being updated in Xcode.

After that it normally works.

Answer (score 3):

What works for me was to use "Set date and time automatically" in my date & Time Control panel. After doing this the timestamps error disappeared and I was able to codesign. Daniel

Comment: This also worked for me. Not even sure how my setting was turned off!

Answer (score 3):

```
$sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

We just had the same error in our automated build, which calls codesign

```
timestamps differ by XXX seconds - check your system clock
```

turns out it was caused by automatic XCode update, which did not have the EULA accepted. The fix was to login to the machine, run XCode.app and accept the T&Cs on startup.